# Adding numbers into 2 totals and put into each its own variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Hope you can help me with this little puzzle.

I have ONE txt file looking like this:

> firstnumbers
>
> 348.92
>
> 237
>
> 230
>
> 329.31
>
> secondnumbers
>
> 18.21
>
> 48.92
>
> 37
>
> 30
>
> 29.31

So a txt file with one Column that has 2 strings and some numbers on each line.

I want to take the total of each column and put it into each variable like say $a and $b
Yes it is 1 column, just to make sure no misunderstanding

It's pretty easy, if I use 2 files with each column of numbers without the headers(strings)

```
$a = (Get-Content 'firstnumbers.txt' | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
$b = (Get-Content 'secondnumbers.txt' | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

But it would be a little more cool to have them in one txt file, like the aforementioned with a header over each row of numbers.

I've tried removing the the headers with i.e. `$a.Replace("first", $null).Replace("sec", $null) and then doing a $b.Split(" ")[1,2,3,4,5]` ending with `| measure -sum`
That gives me the correct number of firstnumbers - but it won't work if I don't keep the specific set of numbers each time. They'll change and there's gonna be more or less of them.

It should be pretty easy I'm guessing. I just can't to seem wrap my head around it at the moment.

Any advice would be awesome!

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$file = "C:\path\to\your.txt"

[IO.File]::ReadAllText($file) | % {
  $_ -replace "`n+([0-9])", ' $1' -split "`n"
} | ? { $_ -ne "" } | % {
  $a = $_ -split " ", 2
  $v = $a[1] -split " " | Measure-Object -Sum
  "{0}`t{1}" -f ($a[0], $v.Sum)
}
```

Output:

```
firstnumbers    1145,23
secondnumbers   163,44
```

Comment: Awesome stuff. It works too, and you get a couple of strings to have fun with :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, rather than parsing the text as one big blob, you could test each line to see if it contains a # or text, if it's text, then it triggers the creation of a new entry in a hashtable where the sums are stored:

```
# C:\Temp> get-content .\numbers.txt | foreach{
    $val=0;
    if([Decimal]::TryParse($_,[ref]$val)){
        $sums[$key]+=$val
    }else{
        $sums += @{"$_"=0}; #add new entry to hashtable
        $key=$_;}
    } -end {$sums}

Name                           Value                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                       
secondnumbers                  163.44                                                                                                                      
firstnumbers                   1145.23
```

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, the $sums variable persists for each run which causes problems if you run this command twice. You could call `Remove-variable sums` after each run, or add it to the `end` processing block like this:

```
# C:\Temp> get-content .\numbers.txt | foreach{
    $val=0;
    if([Decimal]::TryParse($_,[ref]$val)){
        $sums[$key]+=$val
    }else{
        $sums += @{"$_"=0}; #add new entry to hashtable
        $key=$_;}
    } -end {$sums; remove-variable sums;}
```

Comment: Cool approach, works too! (though beware you can only run this once as the values increments each time run it seems)

Comment: @Pieinacup This script does not reset the `$sums` before it runs. You could do that manually or update the script accordingly. See my edits.